# Totally ordered sets. Give a real life example of a total order relation on the set of all existing images on the internet

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Provided that we have some information on all the existing images on the Internet, I'm asked to define a **total order relation** on the set by proving that it's reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive.

I was thinking on defining the relation as being "less than or equal in file size" (provided that we know the file size of each of the existing images) but i'm stuck at proving the anti-symmetric property.

In order to prove the relation is anti-symmetric i'm trying to show that the implication $$\forall x,y \in A: (x \preceq y \wedge y \preceq x) \implies x = y$$is never false.
$$\exists (x, y) \in A : (x \preceq y \wedge y \preceq x \wedge x \neq y)$$

However, given two images x, y $\in A$ (the set of all images on the internet), i can show that $x \preceq y \wedge y \preceq x$ but they can easily meet the $x \neq y$ statement if both images are equal in file size, so the relation is never anti-symmetric.

Maybe i'm missing something or my example isn't a relation order at all, would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can't show that your relation is a total order, because it isn't one, because it often happens that different images have identical file sizes. You can fix it by introducing some secondary criterion to  break ties.

Comment: The set in question is finite. Choose any bijection to a subset of the natural numbers and then use the obvious induced order relation.

Comment: Or just use equivalence classes to identify files of the same size... do you want each image to be uniquely represented?

Comment: JackM and David, OP was asked to give a *real life* example of a total order on the set of all images. Not an arbitrarily chosen one or one on the set of equivalences classes of the set of images.

Comment: There is also the possibility of using md5/sha1 hashes on the files but then again i'm not sure if I can use inequalities on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the relation "less than or equal in file size" isn't a total order, because it isn't antisymmetric. Two different images may have the same file size, so $x\preceq y$ and $y \preceq x$ but $x \neq y$. (Of course, if you want to *prove* that the relation isn't a total order, you have to actually go out and find two different images on the internet that have the same file size.)

The relation might not be a total order, but it's still interesting. It's a great example of a [total preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_preorder): a relation which is total and transitive but not necessarily antisymmetric.

Here's a higher-level view of what went wrong. The size of a file is just a natural number, say the number of bits in the file. We know how to order natural numbers with the relation $\leq$, and *that* ordering is a total order. The relation you defined is closely related to $\leq$, so you might wonder why your relation isn't also a total order. Well, the problem isn't in the natural numbers; it's in the "file size" function. If the function were [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function), then it would define a total order on its domain. Conversely, because the function is not injective, it doesn't define a total order on its domain. (Note that this whole paragraph is a fancy way of restating what you've already said.)

Comment: So, basically if we define $R$ as ${f(x) <= f(y)}$ for $f:Image \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as the function that takes an Image as argument and returns a natural number as the file size, would the relation $R$ still not be of a total order?

Comment: Nvm, just found my answer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). "If X is any set and f an injective function from X to a totally ordered set then f induces a total ordering on X by setting x1 < x2 if and only if f(x1) < f(x2)."

Comment: That definition of $R$ is the relationship I alluded to. So no, $R$ is not a total order because **$f$ is not injective**.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisCulter, appreciate your time!

Comment: No prob, glad I could help!